# Variable doesn't change its value in response to input

Tags: c#

I'm actually quite new to programming and maybe I'm just tired but I can't find the problem here. The `result` doesn't seem to change its value. As you can see, the first input is `product`, second is `city` and lastly it's the `amount` of that product we want. The program has to print the final price (`result`).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string product = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    string city = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    double amount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    double result;
    if (city == "Sofia")
    {
        if (product == "coffee")
        {
            result = amount * 0.50;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        else if (product == "water")
        {
            result = amount * 0.80;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        else if (product == "beer")
        {
            result = amount * 1.20;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        else if (product == "sweets")
        {
            result = amount * 1.45;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        else if (product == "peanuts")
        {
            result = amount * 1.60;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
    }
    else if (city == "Plovdiv")
    {
        if (product == "coffee")
        {
            result = amount * 0.40;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        else if (product == "water")
        {
            result = amount * 0.70;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        else if (product == "beer")
        {
            result = amount * 1.15;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        else if (product == "sweets")
        {
            result = amount * 1.30;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        else if (product == "peanuts")
        {
            result = amount * 1.50;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
    }
    else if (city == "Varna")
    {
        if (product == "coffee")
        {
            result = amount * 0.45;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        else if (product == "water")
        {
            result = amount * 0.70;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        else if (product == "beer")
        {
            result = amount * 1.10;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        else if (product == "sweets")
        {
            result = amount * 1.35;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        else if (product == "peanuts")
        {
            result = amount * 1.55;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You convert `city` to lower case, then compare using an upper case initial letter! That will not end well.

i.e. you need

`if (city == "sofia")`

etc.

Your line by line debugger could be used to verify this. Do spend some time learning how to use that. Debugging more important than being able to type code.

Comment: Oh I thought it didn't matter! Thanks :)

Comment: It wont matter if you do`city.Equals("SoFiA", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 1):

Can you see how combersome the code is? Let's *split* the implementation into *model* and *business logic* (C# 6.0):

```
// Dictionary of dictionary; a better solution is to implement a custom class for it 
private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> s_Model = 
  new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    { "Sofia", new Dictionary<string, double>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
      { "coffee", 0.80},
      { "beer", 1.20},
      { "water", 0.50} } },

    { "Plovdiv", new Dictionary<string, double>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
      { "coffee", 0.70},
      { "water", 0.45} } },
  };
```

Than just use the *model*; try obtaining `products` for the provided `city`; then looking for `price` for the required `product`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // It's the Model that should take case into account
    string product = Console.ReadLine();
    string city = Console.ReadLine();
    double amount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Dictionary<string, double> products = null;
    double price;

    if (!s_Model.TryGetValue(city, out products)) 
      Console.WriteLine("Incorrect city"); 
    else if (products.TryGetValue(products, out price))
      Console.WriteLine("Incorrect product");
    else
      Console.Write((amount * price).ToString("F2"));
}
```

Comment: C# 6.0+ . You should mention that.

Answer (score 0):

As Bathsheba said, you need to change your comparison to lowercase too as the comparison is exact. Also I would recommend putting a `Console.ReadKey();` at the end so it doesn't close before you get a result.

Example:

```
    Console.Write("Product: ");
    string product = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    Console.Write("City: ");
    string city = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    Console.Write("Price: ");
    double amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    double result;
    if (city == "sofia")
    {
        if (product == "coffee")
        {
            result = amount * 0.50;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I put the `Console.Write();`there for readability when running so I could test it.

Also with the many `if`'s I would recommend a switch statement.

eg.

```
 switch(city)
        {
            case "sofia":
                switch (product)
                {
                    case "coffee":
                        result = amount * 0.50;
                        Console.WriteLine(result);
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case "plovdiv":
                switch (product)
                {
                    case "coffee":
                        result = amount * 0.40;
                        Console.WriteLine(result);
                        break;
                } 
                break;
        }
```

Comment: This seems handy :)

Answer (score 0):

Someones seen the lowercase issue already. but also as an alternative to the nesting that you have. In the interest of clean code, change to a switch statement to reduce nesting and to improve the readability of your code.

```
 var product = "coffee";
            var city = "VarNa";
            var amount = 10.00;
            double result;

            switch (city.ToLower())
            {
                case "sofia":
                    switch (product)
                    {
                        case "coffee":
                            result = amount * 0.50;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            break;
                        case "water":
                            result = amount * 0.80;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            break;
                        case "beer":
                            result = amount * 1.20;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            break;
                        case "sweets":
                            result = amount * 1.45;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            break;
                        case "peanuts":
                            result = amount * 1.60;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case "plovdiv":
                    switch (product)
                    {
                        case "coffee":
                            result = amount * 0.40;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            break;
                        case "water":
                            result = amount * 0.70;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            break;
                        case "beer":
                            result = amount * 1.15;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            break;
                        case "sweets":
                            result = amount * 1.30;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            break;
                        case "peanuts":
                            result = amount * 1.50;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case "varna":
                    switch (product)
                    {
                        case "coffee":
                            result = amount * 0.45;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            break;
                        case "water":
                            result = amount * 0.70;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            break;
                        case "beer":
                            result = amount * 1.10;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            break;
                        case "sweets":
                            result = amount * 1.35;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            break;
                        case "peanuts":
                            result = amount * 1.55;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
```